# How to generate dynamic parameters for script cmdlet by reading an msbuild project?

Tags: powershell, msbuild

I'm attempting to create a script cmdlet with dynamic parameters for each of the targets in an MSBuild project file.  It's working with one minor annoyance - it only autocompletes the static parameters until I type the first character(s) of a target parameter.

My script with the cmdlet "Make-Project" follows.

What would cause DynamicParam to not return parameters unless the first part of the parameter is entered?

```
Set-Alias mk Make-Project

function Make-Project
{
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName="Build")]
    PARAM(
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Build")]
        [Switch]$Build,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Clean")]
        [Switch]$Clean,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Rebuild")]
        [Switch]$Rebuild,

        [ValidateSet( "q","quiet", "m","minimal", "n","normal", "d","detailed", "diag","diagnostic" )]
        [string]$BuildVerbosity,

        [Switch]$CertificationBuild,

        [Switch]$BuildDebug
    )

    PROCESS
    {
        # Defaults
        $certBuild = ""
        $target = "Usage"
        $buildTarget = "Build"
        $verbosity = "minimal"
        $configuration = "release"

        if ( [System.Convert]::ToBoolean( $env:project_build_debug ) )
            { $configuration = "debug" }

        foreach( $paramName in $MyInvocation.BoundParameters.Keys )
        {
            switch -RegEx ( $paramName )
            {
                "(?i)CertificationBuild"    { $certBuild = "cert" }
                "(?i)^(Build|Clean|Rebuild)$"   { $buildTarget = $paramName }
                "(?i)^BuildVerbosity$"      { $verbosity = $MyInvocation.BoundParameters[ $paramName ] }
                "(?i)^BuildDebug$"      { $configuration = "debug" }
                default             { $target = $paramName }
            } 
        }
        $msbuildexe = Get-MSBuildExe
        if ( $msbuildexe.Contains( "v4.0" ) )
            { $cmd = "$msbuildexe /v:$verbosity $certBuild /m /property:Configuration=$configuration /property:BuildTarget=$buildTarget /target:$target /property:CLR4=1 Project.proj" }
        else
            { $cmd = "$msbuildexe /v:$verbosity $certBuild /m /property:Configuration=$configuration /property:BuildTarget=$buildTarget /target:$target /tv:3.5 Project.proj" }
        Write-Host $cmd
        Invoke-Expression $cmd
    }

    DynamicParam
    {
        $projFile = '.\Project.Proj'
        $projXml = [xml]( Get-Content $projFile )

        $paramDictionary = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary
        $projXml.Project.Target | % { 
            $paramName = $_.Name
            $attribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
            $attribute.ParameterSetName = "__AllParameterSets"
            $attribute.Mandatory = $false
            $attributeCollection = New-Object System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]
            $attributeCollection.Add($attribute)

            $param = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter( $paramName, [Switch], $attributeCollection )
            $paramDictionary.Add( $paramName, $param )
        }
        return $paramDictionary
    }
}

function Get-MSBuildExe
{
    $bitness = ""
    if ( $env:PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE -eq "AMD64" )
        { $bitness = "64" }

    $msbuildexe = "$env:SystemRoot\Microsoft.NET\Framework${bitness}\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe"
    if ( -not (Test-Path $msbuildexe) )
        { $msbuildexe = "$env:SystemRoot\Microsoft.NET\Framework${bitness}\v3.5\MSBuild.exe" }

    $msbuildexe
}
```

Comment: do you mean you can't hit tab after entering the cmdlet name and you have to type "B", "C" or "R" (for Build, clean or Rebuild) then hit tab for autocomplete to do it's thing? If so this is because the commandline won't know with param set you want to use until you give it a hint.

Comment: Yes.  I had assumed the "__AllParameterSets" param set name would allow it to go ahead and return those dynamic switches.  If I enter the first character of the dynamic switch - with no other static switches - the tab-completion works for all the dynamic switches.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest that you not add a bunch of switch parameters.  Instead, add one dynamic parameter named "Target" and add a ValidateSet attribute to it with the list of targets.

This is a helpful article.

http://robertrobelo.wordpress.com/2010/02/12/add-parameter-validation-attributes-to-dynamic-parameters/

Comment: Except that there's no tab-completion / discovery with switch values, only switches.  The ability to not have to remember and type a full target name was my objective.

Comment: With PowerTab there is. ;)  And you will get an error message with the list of valid values if you supply a bad target name.